# Spark Length function in substring type mismatch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12 I got the following:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Seq(("1987.01.01"))
      .toDF("Input")
      .select( 
        col("Input"), 
        to_date(col("Input"), "yyyy.M.d").as("format"),
        length(col("Input")),
        substring(col("Input"),1, length(col("Input")).cast("int")+0 )
      ).show()



    command-1067744798817014:7: error: type mismatch;
     found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
     required: Int
        substring(col("Input"),1, length(col("Input")).cast("int")+0 )
                                                              ^
```

So I guess I have the wrong "length" function, via implicit import or something?

This works

```
Seq(("1987.01.01"))
  .toDF("Input")
  .select( 
    col("Input"), 
    to_date(col("Input"), "yyyy.M.d").as("format"),
    length(col("Input"))
  ).show()


+----------+----------+-------------+
|     Input|    format|length(Input)|
+----------+----------+-------------+
|1987.01.01|1987-01-01|           10|
+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substring` method in Scala API only accepts integers for the second and third arguments. If you want to pass columns, you need to use `expr` to use the Spark SQL API `substring` method:

```
Seq(("1987.01.01"))
      .toDF("Input")
      .select( 
        col("Input"), 
        to_date(col("Input"), "yyyy.M.d").as("format"),
        length(col("Input")),
        expr("substring(Input, 1, length(Input) + 0)")
      ).show()

+----------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
|     Input|    format|length(Input)|substring(Input, 1, (length(Input) + 0))|
+----------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
|1987.01.01|1987-01-01|           10|                              1987.01.01|
+----------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
```